# How to set coloring of tags in ngTagsInput?

Tags: angularjs, ng-tags-input

I want to use ng-tags-input in my project.

I try to set diffrent color for each tag according to color property object in array.

Here is [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/W5bjrwN5riL94i2jhOP3?p=preview) I am  working on.

For this purpose I need to override tag-item css class in ng-input template.

Here is the example of ng-input template:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="tag-template">
       <div class="tags-input" ng-style="{background: data.color}">

      <span>{{$getDisplayText()}}</span>
      <a class="remove-button" ng-click="$removeTag()">&#10006;</a>
  </div>
```

in this row I try to override tags-input css class:

```
 <div class="tags-input" ng-style="{background: data.color}">
```

And here is result I get:

[image]

as you can see on left and right edges not colored.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?And how to override the tags-input css class??

Comment: I've never used this library before, but it has a guide, with examples and everything, showing how to use a custom template for tags: http://mbenford.github.io/ngTagsInput/documentation/guides/custom-templates

Comment: @JBNizet, I red the documentation but I didn't find my issue there.

Comment: Just click on the link I gave you. It shows how to display a flag in the tag based on data in the tag object. You want to set a color based on data in the tag object. It really is the same problem. The HTML template just need to be adapted in a different way.

Comment: Template dose not give this option!

Comment: It's a HTML template. You can use whatever you would use in any other angular HTML template. Like for example, using ngClass, ngStyle, etc.

Comment: I guess I misunderstanding something. Can you please provide example?

Comment: No. You should try something first. It looks to me that you're just expecting the documentation, or me, to provide you code that is ready to copy and paste. That's not how it works, and that won't teach you anything. Try something. Experiment. Post what you have tried. Tell precisely what the problem is. The documentation has an example that customises the template to add an image with a flag. You just need to adapt it to customize the CSS class of an element. And ngClass can do that. It's documented with examples too.

Comment: I try ng-style fo this purpose

Comment: Good. So, how did it go? If it didn't go well, and you want help, then edit your question, post the code you tried, tell us what you expect this code to do, and tell us what it does instead.

Comment: The problem that I don't know how to override in template tag-item's background. I try to make it with help of ng-style element.but it just looks ugly.

Comment: tag-item class is were the color of tag defined

Comment: You still don't get it. Edit your question. Post your code. Tell us what you expect it to do. Tell us what it does instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the markup, you'll see that the .tags-input div where you apply your background color style is embedded into an `li` element, which has a laft and right padding of 5px. That's why the color is not applied on the full width of the button.

So, make sure to apply your own stylesheet **after** the ng-tags-input stylesheet, and override some CSS rules in order for the `li`to have no padding, and for the div with the background color to have a padding instead:

```
/* override default tag styles for colors to look less ugly */
tags-input .tags .tag-item {
  padding: 0;
  height: 27px;
}

.tags-input {
  padding: 0 5px;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
```

Here's [your plunkr modified](http://plnkr.co/edit/1u0p46lFKAiuzD4uIJB4?p=preview) to make that happen.