# ngTagInput : Dynamic coloring tags and resizable input box

Tags: ng-tags-input

Is there any way, I can color a tag(with different colors) on on-tag-adding event, for a tag entered by user which is not a part of suggestion list? i.e. as a warning to user that he is going to add unknown tag(in red?)

also, How Can I make input box re-sizable vertically as we add more and more tags?

Comment: Dynamic coloring of tags answered by this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36531607/how-to-set-coloring-of-tags-in-ngtagsinput

resizable input still trying for it.

Comment: @MichaelBenford : can you help me with the resizable input box?